# Custom Modal transition not working - example

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to get UIViewControllerContextTransitioning working.

**What I want:**

What I would like to have, is presenting modal view controller with custom animation and transparent background.

**Wthat I did:**

I created animator implementing UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate,

Set for modal controller:

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
self.transitioningDelegate = self;
```

**What I achieved so far,**

Modal controller animates presenting and dismissing view correctly, but after dismissing is finished, entire app becomes black. I used xCode tool to pick what's in window hierarchy, and there is nothing. My guess is, that I changed VC's superview when adding to context's container.

**Animator**

```
@implementation AlertAnimator

const static CGFloat kAnimationDuration = 1.2;

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    UIViewController *to = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *from = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    if (self.transitionType == ModalAnimatedTransitioningTypePresent) {
        [self animatePresentingInContext:transitionContext toVC:to fromVC:from];
    } else if (self.transitionType == ModalAnimatedTransitioningTypeDismiss) {
        [self animateDismissingInContext:transitionContext toVC:to fromVC:from];
    }
}

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
    return kAnimationDuration;
}

- (void)animatePresentingInContext:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext toVC:(UIViewController *)toVC fromVC:(UIViewController *)fromVC {
    CGRect fromVCRect = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:fromVC];
    CGRect toVCRect = fromVCRect;
    toVCRect.origin.y = toVCRect.size.height;

    toVC.view.frame = toVCRect;
    UIView *container = [transitionContext containerView];
    [container addSubview:fromVC.view];
    [container addSubview:toVC.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
        toVC.view.frame = fromVCRect;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}

- (void)animateDismissingInContext:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext toVC:(UIViewController *)toVC fromVC:(UIViewController *)fromVC {
    CGRect fromVCRect = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:fromVC];
    fromVCRect.origin.y = fromVCRect.size.height;

    UIView *container = [transitionContext containerView];
    [container addSubview:toVC.view];
    [container addSubview:fromVC.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
        fromVC.view.frame = fromVCRect;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}

@end
```

**Code example:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oaghtgwvga4nxs4/Test.zip?dl=0

**Question:**

What I am doing wrong and why screen becomes black?

Comment: if this is a presenting animator you should not add the fromVC.view as a subview because its already there. This will cause it to bug out. Try it out and tell me what happens

Comment: thanks @DatForis, I commented out `[container addSubview:fromVC.view];` in `animatePresentingInContext:toVC:fromVC:` but nothing has really changed. any other idea?

Comment: Removing `[container addSubview:toVC.view];` from `animatePresentingInContext:toVC:fromVC:` worked though. Thank you for guiding me there. Please add it as an answer, so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is a presenting animator you should not add the fromVC.view as a subview because its already there. This will cause it to bug out. Try it out and tell me what happens. If its a dismissal animator you shouldn't add the presentingViewController to the hierarchy either.